# Unmet dependencies libre office 14.04 Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

I am having the following error after trying to install libre office from Software Centre.

```
master@master-GA-970A-D3:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:4.2.3~rc3) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-help-en-us : Depends: libreoffice-l10n-en-us
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-l10n-el : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-za : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I have tried for hours to fix it and almost every link, though i am not a linux expert so anything you would like me to paste or run in order to have more info please say. Thank you

**EDIT**: 
**sudo apt-get -f install**

```
master@master-GA-970A-D3:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-crystal libreoffice-style-hicontrast
  libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-style-sifr libreoffice-style-tango
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
26 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/19,7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 75,8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 354061 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1-9764
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/program/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1+elementary2~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.12.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**EDIT 2**: 
**apt-cache policy openoffice-debian-menus**

```
master@master-GA-970A-D3:~$ apt-cache policy openoffice-debian-menus
openoffice-debian-menus:
  Installed: 4.1-9764
  Candidate: 4.1-9764
  Version table:
 *** 4.1-9764 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**apt-cache rdepends openoffice-debian-menus**

```
openoffice-debian-menus
Reverse Depends:
```

**EDIT 3** 
**sudo apt-get purge openoffice-debian-menus**

```
master@master-GA-970A-D3:~$ sudo apt-get purge openoffice-debian-menus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:4.2.3~rc3) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-help-en-us : Depends: libreoffice-l10n-en-us
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-l10n-el : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-za : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**EDIT 4** 
**sudo apt-get -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-depends" purge openoffice-debian-menus**

```
master@master-GA-970A-D3:~$ sudo apt-get -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-depends" purge openoffice-debian-menus
[sudo] password for master: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:4.2.3~rc3) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-help-en-us : Depends: libreoffice-l10n-en-us
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-l10n-el : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-za : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**EDIT 5** 
**sudo apt-get purge libreoffice* openoffice-debian-menus** 
http://pastebin.com/mxxWn3Ss

**EDIT 6** 
**sudo apt-cache policy libreoffice-core**

```
master@master-GA-970A-D3:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-cache policy libreoffice-core
[sudo] password for master: 
libreoffice-core:
  Installed: 1:4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1:4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://bouyguestelecom.ubuntu.lafibre.info/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**EDIT 7** 
**sudo apt-get install libreoffice**

```
master@master-GA-970A-D3:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get install libreoffice
[sudo] password for master: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libreoffice is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:4.2.3~rc3) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-help-en-us : Depends: libreoffice-l10n-en-us
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-l10n-el : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-za : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**EDIT 8** 
 
**sudo apt-get install libreoffice libreoffice-common**

```
master@master-GA-970A-D3:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get install libreoffice libreoffice-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libreoffice is already the newest version.
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-crystal libreoffice-style-hicontrast
  libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-style-sifr libreoffice-style-tango
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
26 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/19,7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 75,8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 354061 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1-9764
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/program/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1+elementary2~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.12.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation (and all comments on this question) has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43327/discussion-on-question-by-j-doo-unmet-dependencies-libre-office-14-04-ubuntu).